# How to create oracle connection in Spring application deployed in JBoss Server? (WrappedConnectionJDK6 cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection)

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, jboss, jdbctemplate

I want to create oracle connection. Currently i am passing jdbc connection to create struct descriptor and here i am getting exception as below. so to avoid this, required to create a java.sql.connection or oracle connection instead of getting from data source.

**org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.jdk6.WrappedConnectionJDK6 cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection**

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.jdk6.WrappedConnectionJDK6 cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection
        at oracle.sql.StructDescriptor.createDescriptor(StructDescriptor.java:160)
        at oracle.sql.StructDescriptor.createDescriptor(StructDescriptor.java:131)
```

Below is the piece of code where the above exception is coming.

```
Connection conn = getDataSource().getConnection();
StructDescriptor itemDescriptor = StructDescriptor.createDescriptor(("EMP_DATA", conn);
StructDescriptor addressDescriptor = StructDescriptor.createDescriptor("EMP_ADDRESS", conn);
ArrayDescriptor descriptor = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("EMP_TABLE", conn);

/** Creating Objects */
Object[] itemAtributes = new Object[] {
        "XXX", "XXX", new STRUCT(addressDescriptor, conn, new Object[] {
                "XXX", "XXX", "XXX" }) };

STRUCT itemObject1 = new STRUCT(itemDescriptor, conn, itemAtributes);

itemAtributes = new Object[] {
        "YYY", "YYY", new STRUCT(addressDescriptor, conn, new Object[] {
                "YYY", "YYY", "YYY" }) };

STRUCT itemObject2 = new STRUCT(itemDescriptor, conn, itemAtributes);

STRUCT[] idsArray = {
        itemObject1, itemObject2 };

ARRAY array_to_pass = new ARRAY(descriptor, conn, idsArray);

/** Calling Procedure */
ps = (OraclePreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement("begin Pr_save_emp(:x); end;");
```

Help in this regared would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error is caused because you are trying to pass JBOSS's WrappedConnection into Oracle's utility class.

According to this https://community.jboss.org/wiki/SetUpAOracleDatasource you need to do the following:

```
Connection dsConn = getDataSource().getConnection(); //JBoss wrapped connection
Connection conn = ((WrappedConnection)dsConn).getUnderlyingConnection(); //Oracle connection
//everything else remains the same
StructDescriptor itemDescriptor = StructDescriptor.createDescriptor(("EMP_DATA", conn);
//...
```

Comment: @GMR Did this help to you? If it is right answer, please consider to accept it, otherwise please provide your solution. Thanks.

Comment: @Nickolas, Thanks for your solution. it works for me now. could please provide the API link for connection methods.

Comment: @GMR excuse me, but what API are you referring to?