# How to create oracle connection in java application, deployed in JBoss Server? (WrappedConnectionJDK8 cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection)

Tags: java, oracle, java-8, jboss, connection

I want to create oracle connection. Currently i am passing jdbc connection to create struct descriptor and here i am getting exception as below. so to avoid this, required to create a java.sql.connection or oracle connection instead of getting from data source.

**org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.jdk8.WrappedConnectionJDK8 cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection**

I found for JDK6 a solution, but it does not work for JDK8
[How to create oracle connection in Spring application deployed in JBoss Server? (WrappedConnectionJDK6 cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15086875/how-to-create-oracle-connection-in-spring-application-deployed-in-jboss-server)

Comment: I would recommend creating a java.sql.Connection instance.  Do not use the Oracle or JBOSS classes unless you must.  There's no good reason to tie yourself to those classes.  The interface is sufficient.

Comment: I'd also recommend using a type IV driver with a URL connection string, not their struct.

Comment: I tried it but still doesn't work, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should use the unwrap method to obtain your instance`datasource.getConnection().unwrap(OracleConnection.class)`

Answer (score 0):

if you use an application server you can configure a Datasource and then use simple code like:

```
public class JDBCConnection {

    @Resource(name = "jdbc/betting-offer-db") private DataSource dataSource;

    public void executeQuery() {
        logger.info("Reloading {}", getCacheNames());
        try (Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection();
             PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(getQuery())) {

            processStatement(stmt);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exception do you obtain?
In your JNDI Tree is present your Datasource JDBC?